# Detecting changes/events in Main Window from other windows

Tags: c#, wpf

- I have a Main Window with buttons and DataGrids.
- The DataGrid are filled with data when the SQL connection is done.
- To make the SQL connection, I click on the button that launches a new window where I can enter my parameters to make the connection on the server and database I want.
- When I click the connection button of this window, in case of succes the window closes and Main Window DataGrids are filled with corresponding data.

**My problem: I can't find a way to let Main Window know that the connection is done and that it has to launch my methods to display data.**

SQL connection and DataGrid filling work fine. I can't call my methods when opening Main Window (since the connection is not done yet) and I can't open the Connection Window first, because if I want to change database later, I would click again on the connection button to make a new connection, and I would like my Main Window to catch the change and display the new data.

I'm on it since yesterday, and I haven't found a working method (or one I could actually understand^^) to make this work.

I'm pretty new with WPF, so maybe there is a functionality I don't know to achieve that?

Thank you!

Comment: It's not functionality but architecture. Your application should implement the MVVM architectural pattern and both windows should use a common view model instance.

Comment: I do use this pattern, but I don't understand it enough to know how a common view model can help me in this case.

Comment: Pass a view model object with the connection-related properties to the DataContext of the parameters window before you open it. The UI elements in the window would two-way bind to those properties. After the window was closed, you still have the view model object and you can access its properties. The view model object could even have an ICommand property that an Apply or Ok button in the parameters window would be bound to. The command would establish the db connection.

Comment: I have something like that in place to pass my data between windows. I already tried to use it for my problem without success. I can try the ICommand thing though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could for example handle the `Closed` event for the connection window in the `MainWindow`:

```
ConnectionWindow win = new ConnectionWindow();
EventHandler eventHandler = null;
eventHandler = (ss, ee) =>
{
    win.Closed -= eventHandler;
    //here the connection window is closed...
};
win.Closed += eventHandler;
win.Show();
```

This event is raises when the window is closed and you can then do whatever you want in the event handler.

Comment: That was one of the solutions I tried, but I must use it wrong because it never worked. I'll try a little more.